# pthread can I get the original argument?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

Heres the snippet of code:

```
pthread_create(&worker->thread, NULL, EagleWorker_begin, worker);

void* EagleWorker_begin(void *obj)
{
    EagleWorker *worker = (EagleWorker*) obj;
}
```

This works fine but is there a way to recover `obj` from the current thread without having to pass it all the way through every function?

Comment: There is no need for the cast. In c `void*` converts to any other pointer to data type without problems.

Comment: @JensGustedt Depends which of the two conflicting language tags actually applies, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can use thread specific data (thread local storage) to make thread wide "globals". The thread code can access these like normal globals. But each thread has it's own global space.

Try this.

```
pthread_create(&worker->thread, NULL, EagleWorker_begin, worker);

__thread EagleWorker *worker;

void* EagleWorker_begin(void *obj)
{
    worker = (EagleWorker*) obj;

    foo();
}

void foo()
{
    worker->whatever = whatever;
}
```

You still need to make sure that you allocate a EagleWorker for each thread and pass it into pthread_create().

Comment: This answers the question - but I'd avoid __thread. It will create thread local object for every instance of a thread whether it needs it or not. I find it better to allocate on the stack. You can wrap it all in a class and never have to worry about it after the thread is created.